# Count the number of packets sent to a server from a client?

Tags: c++, winapi, sockets, winsock, winsockets

So I'm almost done an assignment involving Win32 programming and sockets, but I have to generate and analyze some statistics about the transfers. The only part I'm having trouble with is how to figure out the number of packets that were sent to the server from the client.

The data sent can be variable-length, so I can't just divide the total bytes received by a #define'd value.

We have to use asynchronous calls to do everything, so I've been trying to increment a counter with every FD_READ message I get for the server's socket. However, because I have to be able to accept a potentially large file size, I have to call recv/recvfrom with a buffer size around 64k. If I send a small packet (a-z), there are no problems. But if I send a string of 1024 characters 10x, the server reports 2 or 3 packets received, but 0% data loss in terms of bytes sent/received.

Any idea how to get the number of packets?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm assuming that this is a streaming socket (i.e. TCP) rather than a datagram socket (i.e. UDP)? ... and the problem is that you are receiving stream fragments rather than packets.

Comment: We actually have to implement both TCP and UDP. I'm not quite sure what you mean by stream fragments, but the data is all being read just fine - it's just being queued up until I call recv/recvfrom, and then it grabs as much as it can in one go. I need to calculate around that.

Comment: Do you have to get the stats programmatically, or can you just use Wireshark?

Comment: As far as I know, we have to get them from within the program.

Answer (score 1):

This really boils down to what you mean by 'packet.'

As you are probably aware, when a TCP/UDP message is sent on the wire, the data being sent is 'wrapped,' or prepended, with a corresponding TCP/UDP header.  This is then 'wrapped' in an IP header, which is in turn 'wrapped' in an Ethernet frame.  You can see this breakout if you use a sniffing package like Wireshark.

The point is this.  When I hear the term 'packet,' I think of data at the IP level.  IP data is truly packetized on the wire, so packet counts make sense when talking about IP.  However, if you're using regular sockets to send and receive your data, the IP headers, as well as the TCP/UDP headers, are stripped off, i.e., you don't get this information from the socket.  And without that information, it is impossible to determine the number of 'packets' (again, I'm thinking IP) that were transmitted.

You could do what others are suggesting by adding your own header with a length and a counter.  This information will help you accurately size your receive buffers, but it won't help you determine the number of packets (again, IP...), especially if you're doing TCP.

If you want to accurately determine the number of packets using Winsock sockets, I would suggest creating a 'raw' socket as suggested [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sniffer.aspx).  This socket will collect all IP traffic seen by your local NIC.  Use the IP and TCP/UDP headers to filter the data based on your client and server sockets, i.e., IP addresses and port numbers.  This will give an accurate picture of how many IP packets were actually used to transmit your data.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question but rather a suggestion for a different solution.

What if you send a length-descriptor in front of the data you want to transfer? That way you can already allocate the correct buffer size (not too much, not too little) on the client and also check if there were any losses when the transfer is over.

With TCP you should have no problem at all because the protocol itself handles the error-free transmission or otherwise you should get a meaningful error.

Maybe with UDP you could also split up your transfer into fixed-size chunks with a propper sequence-id. You'd have to accumulate all incoming packages before you sort them (UDP makes no guarantee on the receive-order) and paste the data together.

On the other hand you should think about it if it is really necessary to support UDP as there is quite some manual overhead if you want to get that protocol error-safe... (see the [Wikipedia Article on TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Data_transfer) for a list of the problems to get around)

Comment: Well, according to the assignment PDF I was given, it IS necessary to support UDP. I was hoping to avoid sending the length explicitly, but while reading your post I got an idea for implementing it that just might work. Thanks for the brain-nudge :)

Comment: Always glad to help, even if others just learn from my mistakes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do your packets have a fixed header, or are you allowed to define your own.  If you can define your own, include a packet counter in the header, along with the length.  You'll have to keep a running total that accounts for rollover in your counter, but this will ensure you're counting packets sent, rather than packets received.  For an simple assignment, you probably won't be encountering loss (with UDP, obviously) but if you were, a packet counter would make sure your statistics reflected the sent message accurately.