# Determining Packets Received with Winsock2

Tags: winsock, winsock2, winsockets

Is there a way to determine how many packets where received while using recv() with Winsock? I am looking for a solution to implement at the client, without special requirements on the server side (which I have no control of)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586799/count-the-number-of-packets-sent-to-a-server-from-a-client. As answers to that question point out, it depends on what you mean by a packet.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out, not sure why did not come up on my original search

Comment: sadly that did not answer it either. I cannot use any of those workarounds, would require I control both server and client - i only control client.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to packet-sniff using something like the WinPCap. Then you could correlate the packets captured with the socket used.

Comment: i was hopping there was a better way... connections can be reused and correlation could become iffy